Get description from unrelated table with Table 1 ID between Table 2 From ID and To ID in Power BI direct query mode
I am using Power BI with Direct Query mode pulling data in from Snowflake. The request has the restriction of not being allowed to join or merge tables.
Table 1 is a list of orders with a Priority value.



order_id
priority




AB001
17


AB002
35


AB003
70


AB004
24



Table 2 is a list of Priorities with a priority from value and to value.



fr_priority
to_priority
descr




1
20
PM


21
40
Routine


41
60
Urgent


61
80
Emergency



The end goal for the visualization is to have a column showing the order ID from Table 1 and the priority description from Table 2.



order_id
priority_description




AB001
PM


AB002
Routine


AB003
Emergency


AB004
Routine



Adding a new column from model view to Table 1 does not allow referencing Table 2 columns or DAX functions. In T-SQL, I would normally join the tables:
select T1.order_id, T2.descr
from Table_1 T1 with(nolock)
left outer join Table_2 T2 with(nolock) on T2.fr_priority <= T1.priority and T2.to_priority >= T1.priority 

How can this be achieved in Power BI direct query mode without a join query being sent to Snowflake?

you can try to create a column
Column =
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        'Table 2',
        'Table 1'[priority] >= 'Table 2'[fr_priority]
            && 'Table 1'[priority] <= 'Table 2'[to_priority]
    ),
    'Table 2'[descr]
)



if you want to create a measure,you can try this
Measure =
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        'Table (2)',
        MAX ( 'Table'[priority] ) >= 'Table (2)'[fr_priority]
            && MAX ( 'Table'[priority] ) <= 'Table (2)'[to_priority]
    ),
    'Table (2)'[descr]
)



"Function 'MAXX' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models." - Error when trying to add the column. When trying a measure, it would need to be applied for each record somehow. The Measure error is: "A single value for column in table cannot be determined." I think this would work if I was doing Import mode instead. I may have to solve this in Snowflake if Power BI doesn't have a direct query work-around.

updated the answer, pls have a try.
